Form elements not working on a div overlapping a bootstrap modal
I am trying to overlap div on a bootstrap modal using only css and javascript but the form elements are not even clickable so I cannot change their values except for the select.
bootstrap modal
<button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#sampleModal" id="sampleModalBtn">show modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="sampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title fw-bold"><span class="pe-2">Sample Modal</span></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('overlapDivCon1').style.visibility = 'visible'">overlap div1</button>
                <button type="button">overlap div2</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

overlapping div
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center overlapDivContainer" id="overlapDivCon1">
    <div class="border border-secondary bg-white rounded-3 shadow overlapDiv">
        <div class="p-2 border-bottom">
            <form>
                <a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank">check google</a>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-2" placeholder="type text here">
                <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-2" placeholder="type number here">
                <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-2">
                <select class="form-select form-select-sm mb-2">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
                <textarea></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

css
.overlapDivContainer {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1056;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.overlapDiv {
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}


The issue is with bootstrap modal messing with your custom modal. So if you use dev tools and then delete the bootstrap modal from html then your custom modal with google link works normally and you can add value to inputs too.
Talking about solution. I have tried fixing issue with z-index but it didn't worked so I have used js in which when your custom modal visibility is set to visible it also sets bootstrap modal display to none.
Below is working example also small note don't use js directly inside html element it's not good practice.


function toggleSecondModal() {
  let bootstrapModal = document.querySelector(".modal");
  let customModal = document.getElementById('overlapDivCon1');

  customModal.style.visibility = 'visible';
  bootstrapModal.style.display = "none";
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainDiv {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlapDivContainer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1056;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.overlapDiv {
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="mainDiv">
    <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#sampleModal" id="sampleModalBtn">show modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="sampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title fw-bold"><span class="pe-2">Sample Modal</span></h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <button id="btnOne" type="button" onclick="toggleSecondModal()">overlap div1</button>
            <button type="button">overlap div2</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center overlapDivContainer" id="overlapDivCon1">
      <div class="border border-secondary bg-white rounded-3 shadow overlapDiv">
        <div class="p-2 border-bottom">
          <form>
            <a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank">check google</a>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-2" placeholder="type text here">
            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-2" placeholder="type number here">
            <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-2">
            <select class="form-select form-select-sm mb-2">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <textarea></textarea>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>




Hiding the currently opened modal is actually a good trick and a working one. Thanks!
